# Sencha Touch 2.2.1 concept design with multiple views

Tags: sencha-touch-2, sass

Does anyone know how can I achieve this design using Sencha Touch 2.2.1?

I think I need two Views; A base View with the gradient and another View in another class, which contains all the view components like tabbar title, the image, text field and so on.

Does anyone have a better idea? Is it possible to do this using SASS, assigning the $page-bg-color: as linear gradient and then drawing a white rectangle inside?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aught to be able to paste this straight into senchafiddle.com. I am by no measure a CSS expert to some of this styeling will need a closer look, but this general layout aught to work for you.

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled : true
});

Ext.application({
    name : ('SF' || 'SenchaFiddle'),

    launch : function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
            fullscreen : true,
            style : 'background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top left, #FFFFFF 0%, #00A3EF 100%);',
            layout : 'fit',

            items : [{
                xtype : 'titlebar',
                title : 'Title',
                docked : 'top'
            }, {
                xtype : 'panel',
                layout : 'fit',
                margin : '0 40 0 40',

                items : [{
                    xtype : 'textfield',
                    label : 'Label 1',
                    docked : 'top'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'image',
                    src : 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTL66d6uPSYD6skFSjiBAodALYwTvtqipcjBc5RBsLsMd_IoM94Hg',
                    height : '15em',
                    width : '15em',
                    centered : true
                }]
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

Good luck, Brad